# Moving data from a listbox to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, populate

I need your help moving data from a listbox to a worksheet. 
This listbox contains 14 columns. How can I copy the rows from the listbox to the worksheet?

```
Sub Post ()

    Dim arr
    Dim cnt As Integer
    cnt = ListBox1.ListCount
    arr = ListBox1.List

    With Sheets("DATABASE").ListObjects(1)
      .ListRows.Add
      .DataBodyRange.Cells(.ListRows.Count, 1).Resize(cnt, 14) = arr
    End With
    ListBox1.clear 

End Sub
```

***************** Update 15-01-2019 17:30 **********************
i found this code but it moves 1 line down as pic below

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount
For x = 1 To 14
Sheets("Database").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(i + 1, x - 1) = 
ListBox1.List(i, x - 1) 'ListBoxl.List(i, x)
Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ97J.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a code that solved my problem

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngItem As Long

For lngItem = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(lngItem) Then
        With Sheets(1) '< qualify sheet here
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = 
  ListBox1.List(lngItem, 1)
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = 
 ListBox1.List(lngItem, 2)
        End With
    End If
  Next lngItem

  'Unload Me
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear how you set the target cell, anyhow you can try this (following the logic of your sample):

```
Dim Trg as Range

With Sheets("DATABASE").ListObjects(1)
     Set Trg = .DataBodyRange.Cells(.ListRows.Count, 1)
End With
Trg.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
```

It is easy to paste the content of an array to a range if you can specify the top left cell and the bottom right cell of the target range in advance, so you can say

```
Range("B8:E16") = arr
```

If you only know the the top left cell and want to set the size of the target range dynamically, use `.Resize` like this:

```
Range("B8").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
```

NB: if the target range is smaller than the array then only that amount of data is copied, the rest is omitted.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply , i dont want to use the sheet as table

Comment: thank you so much for your reply , i dont want to use the sheet as table i need to use it as range i mean i want code as copy listbox rows and paste it in specific range

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: I found code and i updated my question , and added pic for error